# How to link rigidbodies with joints while ignoring the other one's drag

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, rigid-bodies

I have two rigidbodies. One has 0 drag and gravity is activated, the other one has 10 drag and gravity de-activated. I hoped that since they were connected, the gravity would be applied like there was 0 drag on it, but that is not the case. It still slows down like it did at 10 when it had gravity. I kind of understand why this would happen. I assume it is because it just transfers force to the other object, so drag still acts upon it.

I also tried parenting one rigidbody to the other rigidbody, and that did not work.

Does anyone know how to connect rigidbodies to apply gravity without drag being included. It doesn't matter if it is in script or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I fixed it. A very specific problem, so I won't post my answer, unless you ask.